# String object has no attribute Name - Titanic data science

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

Hi guys this block of code ran perfectly a day before but today its giving me following errors. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
for dataset in combine:
    dataset['Title'] = dataset.Name.str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)

pd.crosstab(train_df['Title'], train_df['Sex'])
```

I got the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-45b77581ff92> in <module>()
      1 # creating new features from existing ones. Extract names.
      2 for dataset in combine:
----> 3     dataset['Title'] = dataset.Name.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)\.', expand=False)
      4 pd.crosstab(train_df['Title'], train_df['Sex'])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

This code was for titanic data science challenge. Thank you.

Edit: The combine consist of two datasets: train_df and test_df. Here is a snapshot of combine:

```
`combine=['train_df','test_df']`
```

Edit 2: I realized that I had made an error while making 'combine'. I had put them in quotes and when I removed them and made combine like : `combine=[train_df,test_df]` it worked. Thank you all for asking the right questions.

Comment: What is `combine` in your code?

Comment: How is your 'combine' created? It's now returning Strings instead of a more complex structure that you used to get.

Comment: Show how is `combine` created